Are deterministic theories in quantum mechanics superfluous?
There are theories in quantum mechanics that postulate deterministic ways of solving the mysteries of quantum mechanics. One of them is the many worlds interpretation, another Bohmian mechanics, and there are many others. From my research, it seems that some scientists/physicists feel uncomfortable with the idea that there are an infinite number of universes (in the case of MWI) or that there are elements in reality that we cannot fully observe yet in the case of Bohmian mechanics.
This often leads some physicists to claim that deterministic theories in general are superfluous in that it is not needed to explain reality.
I’m having trouble then understanding how exactly deterministic theories would be superfluous. An explanation is superfluous if it doesn’t explain anything and more importantly brings in things that are unneeded to explain the events at hand.
For example, special relativity and Lorentz’s ether theory both have the same exact predictions and explain the events at hand equally well. However, Lorentz’s ether theory has a mysterious element called aether that thus becomes superfluous. In a sense, the explanatory power of each theory is the same, but one postulates more entities. So it makes sense to prefer special relativity over Lorentz’s ether theory and call the latter superfluous since the explanatory power of each is the same.
However, in the case of quantum mechanics, even if a theory like Bohmian mechanics and the many worlds interpretation postulates more, how can they have equal explanatory power to the Copenhagen interpretation? First, as far as I’m aware, the Copenhagen interpretation isn’t really an interpretation and ultimately makes no claims as to what is really going on under the hood. Second, it postulates indeterminacy, which ultimately implies contingencies. In other words, it postulates the lack of a further explanation behind why some things happen a certain way rather than another (such as there being no further explanation as to why a particle is measured at this location vs. another).
When you have a theory that has unexplained contingencies vs. a theory that explains these contingencies, how are their explanatory powers the same?
In a Bayesian sense, this can be modeled as the probability of an event given a hypothesis. Given the Copenhagen interpretation, the P (E|H) will always be between 1 and 0 since we can never definitively rule out a possible outcome. Given a deterministic interpretation, P (E|H) for any event within its scope naturally becomes either 0 or 1, thus removing further possibilities. Doesn’t this mean that deterministic theories have greater explanatory power atleast in principle even if they haven’t been demonstrated yet?

What "needs" to be explained is in the eye of the explainer. Those who feel that contingencies "need" to be explained are welcome to the deterministic explanations. However, looking for something more familiar in areas remote from ordinary experience is not a good justification of such a "need", and those who do not feel it are equally welcome to the hood with nothing under. This played out historically with aether and relativity, most people accepted electromagnetic waves with no medium they spread in. Explanatory "power" of familiar analogies has limits.

@Conifold I just fail to see how the comparison to relativity is anything but a false analogy. There are no unexplained contingencies in either Lorentz’s or Einstein’s theory. And if there are, there are none peculiar to just one. They are both deterministic theories. In quantum mechanics, unless you postulate a theory to explain certain things, we are left with unexplained contingencies. Hence the analogy fails

@abracadabra Incorrect. It depends on how you interpret Bayesianism. You can use probabilities to talk about how likely the evidence is given a theory. For example, the probability that the dice lands on 6 given that it’s a fair dice is 1/6. I don’t see how this is merely a subjective belief. But anyways, this question isn’t about what interpretation of probability is correct. You can call it something else if you wish but the point is that the whole point of theories are to solve contingencies

You are too fixated on contingencies to see what the analogy is. It makes no difference whether it is a medium or determinism that is "needed", the origin of the "need" is the same, yearning for familiarity. Just as waves can be self-propagating contingencies can be self-causing, mechanical and/or deterministic explanations are not the only way, let alone the gold standard, of explanation, unless one makes them so.

@Conifold I think the yearning comes from explaining why X occurs instead of Y. That is the whole basis of science. There is nothing left unexplained by Lorentz’s theory compared to Einstein’s in this sense. There is with quantum mechanics. If an explanation doesn’t tell you why one out of a certain number of possibilities occurs, how could it possibly be an explanation? As per the IEP, “Historically, explanation has been associated with causation: to explain an event or phenomenon is to identify its cause.” Copenhagen doesn’t have causes for many things

I think the difference with your wave analogy and many others, is that a reasonable scope of possibilities is not defined. For example, you could also ask the question “Why is Newton’s second law the way it is formulated vs. another?” The answer to this is we don’t have any further reason to think this. But this doesn’t make this a contingency. For all we know, it may be necessary: there is no scope of alternative possibilities that we have actually tested in some form of a lab. We have done this with QM. When a particle is detected somewhere, we know it was possible to be detected elsewhere.

Let's get the full quote:"Within the philosophy of science there have been competing ideas about what an explanation is. Historically, explanation has been associated with causation: to explain an event or phenomenon is to identify its cause. But with the growth and development of philosophy of science in the 20th century, the concept of explanation began to receive more rigorous and specific analysis." Historically, we had celestial spheres and Aristotle's teleology too, and a modern explanation does not have to tell you why a certain outcome occurs, it can tell you why it is contingent.

@Conifold Yes, the concept of an explanation has been more rigorously defined, but none of them include postulating indeterminism, since indeterminism by its very definition implies a lack of an explanation for contingent things. The “rigorousness” in the article deals with the explanatory power of unobservable things, not with whether an explanation that keeps contingencies at bay is really an explanation or not. But even if your  definition did count as an explanation, we still don’t have an answer since we don’t have full reason to show that events in QM are truly contingent.

You need to expand your horizons on what "explanation" means, in particular, by reading the linked article past the first paragraph. You are in for a surprise already in the second. And we do not have "full reason" to show anything, we are not omniscient, that is not a reason to call comforting fictions "explanation" when we have reason enough to make do without them.

@Conifold I finished reading the article which is very interesting but I don’t see any interpretation of explanation that involves merely accepting the kinds of contingencies I was talking about. Salmon’s causal realism obviously cannot produce an explanation for why a certain measurement occurs  vs. not (lack of cause). Van Frassen, despite viewing explanation as a logical relation, emphasizes that explanations are fundamentally contrastive: they must answer the why question of why one possibility occurs vs. another, the same concept that I was earlier talking about. And so on and so forth.

“And we do not have "full reason" to show anything, we are not omniscient, that is not a reason to call comforting fictions "explanation" when we have reason enough to make do without them” What you fail to realize is that all interpretations of QM are equivalent. So you have no basis by which to say that true randomness is any less or more fictional than a potential explanation that gets rid of that randomness. We can toss a coin and ”make do” with its probabilistic results without needing to know the cause of a result. This doesn’t imply a lack of explanation for why it landed on heads.
